# How to create pattern for method search RegEx on python3?

Tags: python, regex-lookarounds

I am writing a function to retrieve a string from html code with Regular Expression.

ex: `<p class = 3DFormText> [Telephone] <o: p> </ o: p> <w:sdtPr></w:sdtPr> </p>`
for this, I want to get `[Telephone]`, so the format for the string I want to receive is `[anything]`. But I do not know this pattern of method search of Regular Expressions. So anyone please help me create this or give me any suggestions.

Comment: Don't try to parse markup like html with regular expressions .  It's not sufficient and ends up helping very little.  What you want for parsing html is https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: just use BeautifulSoup4 (that's the name of the package CASE SENSITIVE)

Comment: As @DanielFarrell said, it's better to use a HTML/XML parser rather than a regex. You could use [Parsel](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel), [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), etc

Comment: Is that actually HTML, or is it XML (e.g. XHTML embedded in an XML-based word processor document of some kind)?

Answer (score 0):

Better use [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

you can also run `pip install BeautifulSoup4` (case sensitive)

but if you insist, Try improving this pattern, I just made it so it's not 100% perfect of course, and this matches only opening tag

```
<[A-Za-z]+\s*(\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]\s*=*"*[A-Za-z0-9\(\)]*"*)*>
```

it matches `<tag ANY="ANY" checked>` and attributes are optional of course.

it mached my dummy tag

```
<tag required name1="ahmed" name="mohamed" person="idk" whatever="whatever" checked >
```

note that I made it accept attributes Capitalized (first letter) just because html accepts them nothing else feel free to remove that if you want.